# Adding text format with exception to date

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to sum amounts found under identical headers. While it work well, i found that if any column format is left as General, all leading zeros drop even if not being combined but if I change all column formats to text, the dates are now serial numbers.

Is there a way to change all values to text unless they have a "/" to address not updating 01/01/2022 for instance before the code combines values.

Thanks for looking!

```
Sub Combine_Duplicate_Headers()

'Sums amounts under duplicate headers
Dim r As Range:         Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Dim rc As Integer:      rc = r.Rows.Count
Dim AR() As Variant:    AR = r.Value2
Dim SD As Object:       Set SD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim v As Variant

For i = 1 To UBound(AR, 2)
    If Not SD.exists(AR(1, i)) Then
        SD.Add AR(1, i), Application.Index(AR, 0, i)
    Else
        v = SD(AR(1, i))
        For j = 2 To UBound(v)
            v(j, 1) = v(j, 1) + AR(j, i)
        Next j
        SD(AR(1, i)) = v
    End If
Next i

r.ClearContents

For col = 0 To SD.Count - 1
    Cells(1, 1 + col).Resize(rc, 1).Value = SD.items()(col)
Next col
  For rc = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
 
     Columns(rc).EntireColumn.AutoFit
     Next
     
End Sub
```

Comment: You'd need to loop over each element in `SD.items()(col)` and check for `/`, then apply the Text format to the non-date cells before populating the data.

Comment: Could you please step through that a little? I am crash coursing my way through VBA and trying to dissect and absorb why and what parts of code touch. This was prebuilt but was realized the formatting issue recently when zeros dropped. I thought I would need to add the code to the front so i added a .NumberFormat="@" line but obviously that's not quite right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the comments:

```vb
Dim arr, indx As Long
'...
'...
'...
For col = 0 To SD.Count - 1
    arr = SD.items()(col) 'get the array of values
    With Cells(1, 1 + col).Resize(rc, 1)
        'loop the array and check for dates (assuming your dates contain /)
        For indx = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(arr(indx), "/") = 0 Then .Cells(indx).NumberFormat = "@"
        Next indx
        .Value = arr 'fill the values
    End With
Next col
```

**EDIT** - forget the code above - all you need to do is change

`AR = r.Value2`

to

`AR = r.Value`

since `Value2` doesn't support Date values

Comment: here is a onedrive link to a dummy file with the module included. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtU85o39fc_WrAdI4MpVZtRQ0Q0w?e=fZuBpD

Comment: I should have seen this earlier but i think your problem is the use of `AR = r.Value2` instead of `AR = r.Value`   The issue is that `Value2` doesn't support Dates  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2#:~:text=Value2%20property%20doesn%27t%20use%20the%20Currency%20and%20Date%20data%20types

Comment: ok i must be doing something wrong. Everything is being deleted when i change out that code. I also tried to change the r.Value but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Excellent. sorry, i misunderstood. That simple change worked perfectly. Thank you.